# I want to check whether a page is using cookies or not?

Tags: cookies, httpcookie

Is it possible that I hit a page and in response I get the information that this page is using cookies.

Comment: DO you want to do this in a browser or from the command line or through code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which tools you are using, but the cookies are set using HTTP headers, so look in the headers and you will see all the cookie information.

Using curl, --dump-headers may be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming c# from your "httpcookie" tag.

Use HttpWebRequest and make sure to assign its CookieContainer property before making the request. When the request completes, check the response.Cookies.